# QueryOver With Custom Projection and Query Parameter

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I've defined a query in a class with a property, but am trying to build a fairly complex query using the property and have run into NHibernate telling me that it could not resolve property: DueDate.

My Query class looks like this:

```
public class SomeQuery {
  public DateTime DueDate { get; private set; }
  public SomeQuery(DateTime dueDate) {
    DueDate = dueDate;
  }

  public QueryOver GetQueryOver() {

    PrimaryObject po = null;
    SubObject so = null;

    return QueryOver.Of<PrimaryObject>(() => po)
      .JoinAlias(() => so.SubObjects, () => so)
      .Where(
        Restrictions.Le(
          DateProjections.DateDiff("d", () so.Value, () = DueDate), 
          0
        )
      );
  }
}
```

I've implemented the DateProjections Class exactly as described in Andrew Whitaker's blog [QueryOver Series - Part 7: Using SQL Functions](http://blog.andrewawhitaker.com/blog/2014/08/15/queryover-series-part-7-using-sql-functions/)

The contents of the `PrimaryObject` and `SubObject` aren't really important to the example except in the following:

```
public class PrimaryObject {
   public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
   public List<SubObject> Implementations { get; set; }
}

public class SubObject {
  public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string Value { get; set; }
}
```

For Mappings, you can assume that these fields are mapped to the database in sensible ways, as I don't feel like that is where the issue is.

When I try to use this query in a test, like the following:

```
var testDate = new DateTime(2015, 06, 01);
IEnumerable<PrimaryObject> result = repository.FindAll(new SomeQuery(testDate));
```

I get a `NHibernate.QueryException`:

```
NHibernate.QueryException : could not resolve property: DueDate of: PrimaryObject
```

Clearly, I've got an unmapped property, and that is causing the projection to have heartburn.

*Looking for a minimal ceremony solution to getting the DueDate mapped.*  I've looked at Andrew's examples in [QueryOver Series - Part 9: Extending QueryOver to Use Custom Methods and Properties](http://blog.andrewawhitaker.com/blog/2015/01/28/queryover-series-part-9-extending-queryover-using-custom-methods-and-properties/), but it felt like a lot of ceremony.

I've also googled for solutions, but my google foo failed me..

Suggestions? Solutions?

Comment: Is that actual code around the DateDiff call? It doesn't look like compilable c# code.

Comment: It does compile, I just reduced the number of joins and where's from my original until I had a minimal subset of compiling, but broken code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DateDiff` implementation on the blog is assuming you wish to calculate the difference between database fields. This isn't what you want: you want to compare one database field with a constant.

You'll have to refactor the set of `DateProjections` methods to allow you to pass a constant as a parameter:

```
public static class DateProjections
{
    private const string DateDiffFormat = "datediff({0}, ?1, ?2)";


     // Here's the overload you need
    public static IProjection DateDiff
                  (
                    string datepart,
                    Expression<Func<object>> startDate,
                    DateTime endDate
                  )
   {
         return DateDiff(
                           datePart,
                           Projections.Property(startDate),
                           Projections.Constant(endDate)
                        );
   }        
    // Keeping Andrew Whitaker's original signature
    public static IProjection DateDiff
                             (
                                string datepart, 
                                Expression<Func<object>> startDate,
                                Expression<Func<object>> endDate
                             )
    {
        return DateDiff(
                         datePart,
                         Projections.Property(startDate),
                         Projections.Property(endDate)
                       );
    }
    // Added a function that's shared by 
    // all of the overloads
    public static IProjection DateDiff(
             string datepart,
             IProjection startDate,
             IProjection endDate)
    {
        // Build the function template based on the date part.
        string functionTemplate = string.Format(DateDiffFormat, datepart);

        return Projections.SqlFunction(
            new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.Int32, functionTemplate),
            NHibernateUtil.Int32,
            startDate,
            endDate);
    }
}
```

Now you can invoke it like so:

```
public QueryOver GetQueryOver() {

   PrimaryObject po = null;
   SubObject so = null;

   return QueryOver.Of<PrimaryObject>(() => po)
     .JoinAlias(() => so.SubObjects, () => so)
     .Where(
        Restrictions.Le(
          DateProjections.DateDiff("d", () => so.Value, DueDate), 
          0
        )
  );
}
```

Comment: Nothing like cargo culting, someone else's code without really understanding what it was doing.  Your example has expanded my understanding when working with QueryOver and Projections.